# Is there a faster way to switch between Firebase accounts?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

The current method I use to switch between accounts is using the Firebase CLI with:

```
firebase logout
firebase login
```

The browser then opens and then I give the CLI permissions.

Is there any other method that is faster than this one, or a way that the CLI can remember that I have already given it permissions on that account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase CLI does not have fast user switching like some of Google's web clients do. You'll have to grant permission each time you switch.

You could [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), although I'm not sure this will ever make it to the top of a list.